# How to get Post ID with the Add Filter Function

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I'm writing a plugin and am trying to figure out how to add data to the end of a post based on some Custom Meta Information.

So i've done this so far:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'AppendMeta');
```

And here is the "AppendMeta" function

```
AppendMeta($content) {
    echo $content; // Echo out post content
    $PersonName = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PersonName', true);
    echo 'Person: ' . $PersonName;
}
```

That code works if I replace $post->ID with the id of the post, but I need it to work based on the post the user is currently navigating.  How would I pass the post id in as a parameter?  $post->ID doesn't work in this scenario and I can't find out why.

Comment: Quick note: when hooking into a filter hook your function should return the filtered variable instead of echoing it out.

Comment: Is that convention or is there a reason why?

Comment: its convention for a reason, filter hooks let you alter/modify a value and expect that value  to be returned, that's just how they work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind, found out I can use `get_the_ID();`.

This function will return the post id inside the `the_content` filter. The function simply declares the global `$post` object and returns its ID.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse51205_content')
wpse51205_content($content) {
    echo $content; // Echo out post content
    $PersonName = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'PersonName', true);
    echo 'Person: ' . $PersonName;
}
```

If you don't want to use `get_the_ID()`, you simply need to declare the `$post` object global before using it:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse51205_content')
wpse51205_content($content) {
    global $post;
    echo $content; // Echo out post content
    $PersonName = get_post_meta($post->ID), 'PersonName', true);
    echo 'Person: ' . $PersonName;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, good to know, probably more reliable that way.

Comment: `get_the_ID()` is still meant to be used inside the loop only. It might work for you well on single pages but a fully reliable way is to access `global $post` variable only like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`the_ID()` is only supposed to be used inside the loop, else you can't rely on it. Better use the `$GLOBALS['post']` object inside your function call.

Comment: the_ID() relies upon the global $post too.